# using macro to simplify the code

Tags: macros, formatting

I got my code working with net and SO help. But now I want to simplify it using macro. I dont know macro, but people says it makes code more simplified.

can some one guide me to have macro for this. How to use it define?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}

\colorbox{black}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep]{\color{white}\textbf {User schema}}}

\[
  \text{Users} \left\{ \begin{tabular}{@{}p{.8\linewidth}@{}}
    \textbf{ID}:  \textcolor{red}{ObjectId} -- Id do registro \\
    \textbf{Name}: \textcolor{red}{String} -- Name co usuario \\
    \textbf{date}: \textcolor{red}{Date} -- Date de Cadastro \\
    \textbf{ren\_date}: \textcolor{red}{Date} -- Data de \\
    \textbf{email}: \parbox[t]{.9\linewidth}{\raggedright\textcolor{red}{String} -- Lorem ipsum dolorsitamet, consecteturadipisicingelit, sed do 
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minimveniam, exercitationullamcolaborisnisi ut 
      aliquipexeacommodoconsequat. Duisautereprehenderit in voluptatevelit esse cillumdolore eu fugiatnullapariatur. Occaecatcupidatat 
      non proident, sunt in culpa quiofficiadeseruntmollit.\strut} \\
    \textbf{accesslog}: \textcolor{red}{Array} \begin{tabular}[t]{@{\ }|l@{}}
      \strut \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
      $\left\{\begin{tabular}{p{.7\linewidth}}
         \textbf{date}: \textcolor{red}{string} Data -- da ocorrncia. \\
         \textbf{user}: \textcolor{red}{ObjectId} -- que executou. \\
         \textbf{action}: \textcolor{red}{String} --  Aço Executada. \\
       \end{tabular}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace$ \\
      $\left\{\begin{tabular}{p{.7\linewidth}}
         \textbf{date}: \textcolor{red}{string} Data -- da ocorrncia. \\
         \textbf{user}: \textcolor{red}{ObjectId} -- que executou. \\
         \textbf{action}: \textcolor{red}{String} -- Aço Executada. \\
       \end{tabular}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace$
    \end{tabular}

    \\
\textcolor{blue} {\hyperlink{page.2}{\textbf {group\_id : }}} \textcolor{red}{ ObjectId } - Id do  grupo. 

  \end{tabular}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\]
```

Comment: Do you have some more stuff before `\begin{document}`?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: yes, packages. I updated

Comment: And is there a `\end{document}` too?

Comment: It is probably unreasonable to make that whole tabular be the subject of a single macro unless you have many similar tables.  But macro simplification can start with something as simple as `\newcommand{\tblkeyword}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}`, which you then can use as `\tblkeyword{ObjectID}` in place of `\textcolor{red}{ObjectID}`.  See the advantage?  If you decide 'red' is the wrong colour, you only need to change the `\newcommand` to have the change propagate through the whole table.  (This is only one example from the not-quite-complete document you have provided.)

Comment: Oh I see, thamks for help. my code will grow more, so this may help. I guess I can add micro for color n making bold attributes in this doc. Right? Can it be applied to anything else? @jon

Comment: Yes, indeed.  Note, however, that I was giving only a very basic example of a macro.  If you have to use a 'tabular' many times to record date, user, and action information, you can write a better command to do that for you so that each 'tabular' is formatted consistently.  If you need flexibility a 'key-value' approach is best; if they are always going to consist of the same 'variables', then a `\newcommand` might suffice.  But, as Christian asked, is this supposed to represent a complete example?  (An `\end{document}` might be missing.)

Comment: @Jon: thanks, but I don't have idea about using command with tabular and also about key value approach, and yeah its not complete example. Complete example is here https://www.sharelatex.com/project/53915feaeef2f99941486f56

Answer (score 2):

You can hide repetitive complicated code in macro definitions and in new environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newenvironment{bracedtabular}
 {$\left\{\begin{tabular}}
 {\end{tabular}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace$}
\newenvironment{lineditems}
 {\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}|l@{}}\\[-\normalbaselineskip]}
 {\end{tabular}\vspace{3pt}}
\newcommand{\group}[2][.]{\textcolor{#1}{\bfseries#2}}
\newcommand{\key}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\longitem}[2][.9\linewidth]{\parbox[t]{#1}{\raggedright#2\unskip\strut}}
\newcommand{\header}[1]{%
  \colorbox{black}{%
    \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep]{\color{white}\bfseries#1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\header{User schema}

\medskip

\text{Users}
\begin{bracedtabular}{@{}p{.8\linewidth}@{}}
\group{ID}:
  \key{ObjectId} -- Id do registro \\
\group{Name}:
  \key{String} -- Name co usuario \\
\group{date}:
  \key{Date} -- Date de Cadastro \\
\group{ren\_date}:
  \key{Date} -- Data de \\
\group{email}:
  \longitem{
    \key{String} -- Lorem ipsum dolorsitamet, consecteturadipisicingelit, sed do 
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
    minimveniam, exercitationullamcolaborisnisi ut aliquipexeacommodoconsequat.
    Duisautereprehenderit in voluptatevelit esse cillumdolore eu fugiatnullapariatur.
    Occaecatcupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa quiofficiadeseruntmollit.
  } \\
\group{accesslog}:
  \key{Array}
  \begin{lineditems}
    \begin{bracedtabular}{@{}p{.7\linewidth}}
    \group{date}:
      \key{string} Data -- da ocorrncia. \\
    \group{user}:
      \key{ObjectId} -- que executou. \\
    \group{action}:
      \key{String} --  Aço Executada. \\
    \end{bracedtabular} \\
    \begin{bracedtabular}{@{}p{.7\linewidth}}
    \group{date}:
      \key{string} Data -- da ocorrncia. \\
    \group{user}:
    \key{ObjectId} -- que executou. \\
    \group{action}:
      \key{String} -- Aço Executada. \\
    \end{bracedtabular} \\
  \end{lineditems}
\group[blue]{\hyperlink{page.2}{group\_id:}}
  \key{ObjectId} - Id do  grupo. 
\end{bracedtabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]